# Federated authentication via OpenID Connect from Azure

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I need to run .NET applications in Azure and have them authenticate against my on-premise directory (via PingFederate).  It appears that ACS is the only way to do federated authentication from Azure, even though it has been [deprecated for over a year](https://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx).  It also seems that ACS does not support OpenID Connect.

So am I correct in thinking it is not possible to do federated authentication via OpenID connect from Azure?  And does anyone know when federation with external identity providers will be added to Azure AD?

Comment: Based on knowledge, ACS is still there and the name is changed to "Microsoft Azure Active Directory Access Control", it does support  federation with external identity providers, such as Google, Yahoo, and Facebook, it also support OAuth 2.0

Comment: @Matt: but not OpenID Connect (which is what Google uses btw)?

Comment: OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol, as its website says; http://openid.net/connect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Federated authentication is supported by Azure AD. Most of our enterprise customers connect their Azure Active Directory to their on-premises directory for federated authentication with Office 365 and other SAAS apps connected with Azure AD.

You can indeed federated your Azure AD with PingFederate and use Azure AD' OpenIDConnect protocol to configure single sign on for your cloud application.

Sign-up for a free trial Azure subscription and create a directory. Use the documentation here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj673460.aspx) and the following sample app (https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) to connect your app' authentication with your directory using OpenIDConnect.
Then, add a verified domain to your directory and federate it with your PingFederate STS by following the guidance here (http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PFS/SSO+to+Office+365+Introduction).

We don't recommend using ACS for this scenario.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first and the last link are broken, could you fix it?